# Protected? getSource and getTarget methods on JGraphT DefaultEdge class

Tags: jgrapht

The methods `getSource()` and `getTarget()` of *DefaultEdge* on *org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge* are protected.

How should I access source and target vertices of each of the edges returned by the `edgeSet()` of *org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleGraph* ?

The code below shows what is happening.

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.jgrapht.UndirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleGraph;

public class TestEdges
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g =
            new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

        String A = "A";
        String B = "B";
        String C = "C";

        // add the vertices
        g.addVertex(A);
        g.addVertex(B);
        g.addVertex(C);

        g.addEdge(A, B);
        g.addEdge(B, C);
        g.addEdge(A, C);

        Set<DefaultEdge> edges = g.edgeSet();

        for(DefaultEdge edge : edges) {
            String v1   = edge.getSource(); // Error getSource() is protected method
            String v2   = edge.getTarget(); // Error getTarget() is protected method
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The "correct" method to access edges source and target, according to [JGraphT mailing list](http://jgrapht-users.107614.n3.nabble.com/help-on-using-getSource-and-or-getTarget-for-edge-td1784423.html) is to use the method `getEdgeSource(E)` and `getEdgeTarget(E)` from the interface `Interface Graph<V,E>` of *org.jgrapht*

the modification of the code is then

```
for(DefaultEdge edge : edges) {
   String v1   = g.getEdgeSource(edge);
   String v2   = g.getEdgeTarget(edge);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue when trying to extract the values of the edges, and although not OP's case, might be helpful for anyone else facing this issue.

When I instantiated my graph and passed it an edge class:

```
DirectedGraph graph = new SimpleDirectedGraph(DefaultEdge.class);
```

Netbeans gave me the option for what **DefaultEdge.class** file to import, I chose the wrong one. I used the **org.jgraph** library instead of the **org.jgrapht**.

If you are using the DefaultEdge class make sure you are using the one from jgrapht.

```
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
```